# Auditing @ElementCollection/@Embeddable with hibernate-envers

Tags: hibernate-envers

I'm trying to audit a collection of @Embeddable objects using hibernate-envers.

According to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6613 support for auditing @ElementCollection was added. This feature doesn't seem to work well: when trying to save several @Embeddable objects with the same revision number NonUniqueObjectException is thrown.

Does anyone have a working example of @ElementCollection+@Embeddable audited with Envers?

Comment: What is the generated DDL? If I remember correctly, the table which stores the collection and the embedded object, should have an index (hence a unique key) on all columns + revision number.

Comment: I create all hibernate/envers tables and their indices manually. The index of embeddable auditing table consists of all columns + REV + REVTYPE (I noticed that there is no REVTYPE=MOD for embeddable, only DEL+ADD), so it should be possible to insert rows with same revision number. 
As far as I understand, the exception is not thrown by BD, it's not getting to row insertion at all. It is caused by saveWithGeneratedId in AbstractSaveEventListener. There, generatedId consists only of DefaultRevisionEntity, REVTYPE and id (joined column), which causes an exception later on.

Answer (score 1):

As of Hibernate 5.2.8, we managed to make it work by these steps:

1. Define the java type as `Set` for the collection of embeddable elements
2. Implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods in the class of the embeddable elements
3. Be sure to create an int column named `SETORDINAL` in the table that holds
   the audit log of said elements (or let hibernate create the tables for you
   by setting the appropriate configuration key).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! This isn't a great answer, because you've not actually written an answer, just pasted a quote without a source. Please read up on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: If any updation happen on collection entity, does audit table storing revtype 1? In my case it stores 2 entry one with revtype 0 and second with revtype 2